# docker: Can't use ls in mount directory

Tags: docker

I use
`docker run -it -v $PWD/website:/var/www/html/website gerbawn/nginx /bin/bash`
to start a docker container. But I can't use ls to look `/var/www/html/website` directory.

[image]

I had change directory permission to 777 but no use.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker help? Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/30101747/6309?

Comment: Thanks, I get the answer.It because selinux

Answer (score 2):

The first link I mentioned "[Permission denied on accessing host directory in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24288616/6309)" seems to be the root cause:
Assign the proper SELinux policy type to the host directory

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t host_dir
```

(host_dir is a path to the directory on host system that is mounted to the container.)

Actually, [since docker 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31334443/6309), you should be able to do a:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD/website:/var/www/html/website:z gerbawn/nginx /bin/bash
                                                    ^^
# or:
docker run -it -v $PWD/website:/var/www/html/website:Z gerbawn/nginx /bin/bash
                                                    ^^
```