# docker-compose, run a script after container has started?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rancher

I have a service that I am bringing up through Rancher via docker-compose. The issue I am running into is that I need to set a password after the container has been deployed.

The way rancher secrets work, is that I set my secret in and rancher will mount a volume on my container with a file containing my secret. I was hoping to be able to execute a script to grab that secret, and set it as a password on my config file.

I don't believe I have a way to get that secret in through the Dockerfile as I don't want the secret to be in git, so I'm left looking at doing it via docker-compose.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Absolutely, that's a fairly normal way of setting secrets. Just add the relevant shell script as (or to) your CMD or ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: to have access to secret without expose in Dockerfile, you can use .env file with docker-compose : https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Hi. This is specific problem. The way to use a separate service as a set UP service is working solution.
But often images provide you some sort of the 'hooks' that can be used. Like [here](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/blob/master/3.1/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/libkafka.sh#L768) for kafka. You need just put a scripts to the "docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" to run some sort of set up.

Answer (score 104):

This is the way I use for calling a script after a container is started without overriding the entrypoint.

In my example, I used it for initializing the replicaset of my local MongoDB

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2.8
    hostname: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/mongod","--bind_ip_all","--replSet","rs0"]
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  mongosetup:
    image: mongo:4.2.8
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    restart: "no"
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "sleep 10 && mongo --host mongo:27017 --eval 'rs.initiate()'"]
```

- In the first part, I simply launch my service (mongo)
- The second service use a "bash" entry point AND a `restart: no` <= **important**

I also use a `depends_on` between service and setup service for manage the launch order.

Comment: This approach seems interesting but for me raises some questions. First, why use the `mongo` image for the `mongosetup` container? Will just any image do? Or is it important that it should be the `mongo` one? Second, you say that setting `restart: no` is important, but why is that? So that setup does not get executed multiple times? Last, I see `sleep 10`? Is that to give mongo time to initialize? Seems tricky to use `sleep` for that...

Comment: @StijndeWitt 

1. "Why use `mongo` image?" 
because the command `mongo --host mongo:27017 --eval 'rs.initiate()'`
which is the 4th element of mongosetup.entrypoint property in the above 
docker-compose, uses `mongo` which is a cli program (mongosh also can be used as a newer alternative) and
this program is pre-installed on `mongo` images.

Comment: @StijndeWitt
2. "you say that setting restart: no is important, but why is that?"
because as the name for this container suggests, this container is for 
setting up replica set for mongo, which means just running the `mongo --host mongo:27017 --eval 'rs.initiate()'`
either from a container that can access the mongo container using `mongo:27017`(both container must be on the same network, like `mongosetup` and `mongo` containers are, in this

Comment: @StijndeWitt
setup, the string `mongo` in `mongosetup` container, maps to the IP of `mongo` container) or from the same container you can run `mongo --eval 'rs.initiate()'`
since in this example the first approach is taken, and as explained the `mongo --host mongo:27017 --eval 'rs.initiate()'` must get executed at least once(preferably only once).
hence `restart: "no"` is set, to let the container shut down after it has run the command successfully.

Comment: @StijndeWitt
3. "I see sleep 10? Is that to give mongo time to initialize?"
yes, it waits for 10 seconds before running the command, because
the mongo daemon in the `mongo` container, must be up and running in order for the command 
to run successfully

Answer (score 73):

The trick is to overwrite the compose COMMAND to perform whatever init action you need before calling the original command.

1. Add a script in your image that will perform the init work that you want like set password, change internal config files, etc. Let's call it `init.sh`. You add it to your image.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM: sourceimage:tag
COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT []
```

The above overrides whatever ENTRYPOINT is defined in the `sourceimage`. That's to make this example simpler. Make sure you understand what the ENTRYPOINT is doing in the Dockerfile from the `sourceimage` and call it in the `command:` of the docker-compose.yml file.

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  myservice:
    image: something:tag
    ...
    command: sh -c "/usr/local/bin/init.sh && exec myexecutable"
```

It's important to use `exec` before calling the main command. That will install the command as the first process (PID1) which will make it receive signals like STOP, KILL (Ctrl-C on keyboard) or HUP.

Comment: executing this causes `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 172: /usr/local/bin/init.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Additionally, removing the first part of the command causes the error `exec: not found`

Comment: Looks like docker isn't treating the `&&` as command chaining. It's treating it and the rest of the line as additional arguments.

Comment: @BurhanAli  I've updated the answer to explicitly call the "shell -c". Also, there are many different combinations of `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` (Dockerfile) and `entrypoint:`/`command:`(docker compose) which can override each other. To keep this answer concise, I reset the ENTRYPOINT so that it doesn't override `command`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you much more elegant that creating another container

Comment: What is `myexecutable` in yml file? I am just trying to run this command as script `redis-server --deamonize yes`. Do i need to use exec?

Comment: @MurtazaHaji. In your case the line would be `command: sh -c "/usr/local/bin/init.sh && exec redid-server --deamonize yes`

Comment: I don't understand the relation between the `command:` and ENTRYPOINT in the sourceimage. If we're using `command:`, then __the CMD__ of the sourceimage _might be_ overridden, not the ENTRYPOINT. Am I missing something?

Comment: @aderchox That's correct, `command` will override the `CMD` instruction in the image. However, the final startup action is obtained by combining `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`. So if `ENTRYPOINT` is for instance `["echo"]`, you can set `CMD` to `"hello"`and this will print "hello". I believe this was done historically to allow different arguments to be specified easily. `ENTRYPOINT` contains the main executable and `CMD` contains the arguments passed to the executable.  You can also set `ENTRYPOINT` to an empty array so that `CMD` or `command` contains the full startup action line, like we do above.

Answer (score 28):

You can also use volumes to do this:

```yaml
services:
  example:
    image: <whatever>
    volume: ./init.sh:/init.sh
    entrypoint: sh -c "/init.sh"
```

Note that this will mount `init.sh` to the container, *not* copy it (if that matters, usually it doesn't). Basically processes within the container can modify `init.sh` and it would modify the file as it exists in your actual computer.

Comment: Got it! I needed `entrypoint: sh -c "sh init.sh"` for it to work properly

Comment: interesting, looks like you mounted it to `./init.sh` instead of `/init.sh`? seeing `sh` twice feels icky 

Comment: using `entrypoint: sh -c "sh /init.sh"`  resolve the issue `sh: /init.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: how to solve "Permission denied" problem?

Comment: you will need to be more specific, but my guess is that the docker process does not have access to `init.sh` on your local computer, so you get this error. either copy the `init.sh` as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/47629959/4021308 or move `init.sh` to somewhere docker would be allowed to access. i would NOT recommend running docker in `--privileged` mode (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35620590/4021308)

Answer (score 2):

docker-compose specify how to launch containers, not how to modify an existing running container.

The [Rancher documentation](http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/latest/en/cattle/secrets/#adding-secrets-using-rancher-cli) mentions that, for default usage of secrets, you can reference the secret by name in the secrets array in the `docker-compose.yml`.

> The target filename will be the same name as the name of the secret.
>   By default, the target filename will be created as User ID and Group ID 0, and File Mode of 0444.
>   Setting external to true in the secrets part will make sure it knows the secret has already been created.
>
> Example of a basic `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: sdelements/lets-chat
    stdin_open: true
    secrets:
    - name-of-secret
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
secrets:
  name-of-secret:
    external: true
```

As illustrated in "[How to Update a Single Running docker-compose Container](https://staxmanade.com/2016/09/how-to-update-a-single-running-docker-compose-container/)", updating a container would involve a "build, kill, and up" sequence.

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <service_name>
```